# Accessing Variables from MY_Controller CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables

As I have read through articles, the best possible way to validate a user in all controllers of my application is to extend my own Controller that extends CI_Controller

But I can't make it work.

What I have is a `members_controller` that extends my `MY_Controller`.

in `MY_Controller` i have this piece of code, just to test if how am I going to utilize this.

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

private $foo;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->foo = 'hello world again';
    }

}
```

in my `members controller`

```
<?php
class Members extends MY_Controller {
    function index() {
         $this->load->view('members');
    }
}
```

in my `members view`

i want to access this variable i just set up, but i don't know how.

i tried echoing it out like this `echo $foo`, like this `$this->foo`

but neither work. thanks much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the variable to your view file.

```
    <?php
    class Members extends MY_Controller {
        function index() {
             $data = array('foo' => $this->foo)
             $this->load->view('members', $data);
        }
    }
```

Now you can refer to $foo inside your view. You may need to declare $this->foo as protected.

There's a video tutorial on MY_Controller that you may find useful at http://codeigniter.tv/a-10/Extending-the-core-MY_Controller-and-beyond

Comment: thanks.. i but can't do it if its a private variable.. hehe.. anyhow thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the variable to the 'members view'.

```
$this->load->view('members',$foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `$foo` as protected and not private.
Then you will be able to access it in your controller that extends MY_Controller.php like this:
`$this->foo`

Answer (score 0):

Today for the first time I used codeigniter 3. In the past I used version 2.x a lot of times. Now I can't extend `CI_Controller`:

**application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

private $data = array();

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Zagreb");
    $this->data['foo'] = "bar";
}
```

**application/controllers/Welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->data['main_content'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('template/template', $this->data); 
}
```

**application/view/home.php**
 (this is view loaded by `$this->data['main_content']`)

If I try to echo any data declared in `MY_Controller`, I get an error.

```
    <?php echo $foo; ?>

A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: foo

Filename: template/header.php
```